# Создание массива на основе двух других массивов

Tags: javascript

Нужно создать массив, в котором элементы будут взяты из двух других массивов. Первый элемент должен быть взят из первого массива, второй элемент должен быть взят из второго массива, третий элемент в новом массиве должен быть взят из второго элемента первого массива и так далее.

Пример:

```
a: ['a', 'b', 'c'] //первый массив
b: ['d', 'e'] //второй массив
array  ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c'] // новый массив, созданный на основе первых двух.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const b = ['d', 'e']

const c = []

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    if (a[i] != null) {
        c.push(a[i])
    }

    if (b[i] != null) {
        c.push(b[i])
    }
}

console.log(c) // ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c']
```

Comment: в итоге будет массив ["a", "e", "c"], если не ошибаюсь

Comment: @garmayev Ошибаетесь, запустите код

Comment: ааа, все, понял. Ваш вариант оптимальней =) Второй if проглядел =)

Comment: за что заминусили-то?

Comment: Как этот код можно прикрутить к объекту в консоле хрома. Test.data = function.... просто не работает?

Comment: Сейчас код выглядит вот так и собственно не работает

`Test.provide = Test.data = function arraaays() {
const c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    if (a[i] !== null) {
        c.push(a[i]);
    }

    if (b[i] !== null) {
        c.push(b[i]);
    }
}

console.log(c);
}`

Comment: @TRIGUN117 а что именно не работает? В вашем коде нет исходных массивов

Answer (score 0):

самое простое, что приходит в голову

```
function sliyaniye(a, b) {
  var k, l = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length+b.length; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
      result.push(a[k]);
      k++;
    } else {
      result.push(b[l])
      l++;
    }
  }
}
```

Сам прекрасно знаю, что код не оптимальный, но по-простому должен сработать...

Comment: `var k, l = 0;` - может, вынести из цикла?

Comment: каюсь, глаза слипаются. Да, их надо вынести из цикла, счас вправлю