# Работа с JavaScript объектами в консоле chrome

Tags: javascript, массивы, google-chrome

У меня есть задание, которое звучит так:

**Компьютер помещает два массива со случайными строками в Test.data. Нужен один список, содержащий один элемент из a, затем один из b и т.д.**

**Пример:**

```
a: ['a', 'b', 'c']    
b: ['d', 'e']    
-> ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c']
```

Я пробовал этот код, но он просто заменяет данные, которые находятся в Test.data

```
Test.provide = Test.data = function arry(a, b) {
const c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    if (a[i] != undefined) {
        c.push(a[i]);
    }

    if (b[i] != undefined) {
        c.push(b[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Ошибка заключается в том, как я использую функцию. Исходные массивы находятся в Test.data. Результат я сохраняю в Test.provide

Все это я делаю в консоле хрома и работаю с готовыми данными.

Comment: "Ошибка заключается в том, как я использую функцию." - как Вы используете функцию?

Comment: Не нужно задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. Вместо этого воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" и внесите изменения в уже существующий вопрос.

Comment: @Igor в данном коде я просто заменяю все данные в Test.data на свой код(код функции) и собственно всё, как сделать это нормально я не знаю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание массива на основе двух других массивов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718037/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function arry(a, b) {
var c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    if (a[i] != undefined) {
        c.push(a[i]);
    }

    if (b[i] != undefined) {
        c.push(b[i]);
    }
}
return c;
}
Test.provide = arry(Test.data.a, Test.data.b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так:

```
var Test = {};
Test.data = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    ['e', 'f'],
];

Test.provide = (function(a, b) {
  var minLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
  var c = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
    c.push(a[i]);
    c.push(b[i]);
  }

  if (a.length > b.length) {
      c = c.concat(a.slice(minLength, a.length));
  } else if (a.length < b.length) {
      c = c.concat(b.slice(minLength, b.length));
  }

  return c;
}) (Test.data[0], Test.data[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Во первых:

```
const c = []; - это уже ошибка. Используй var или let

Test.provide = function arry(Test.data.a, Test.data.b) {
var c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    if (a[i] != undefined) {
        c.push(a[i]);
    }

    if (b[i] != undefined) {
        c.push(b[i]);
    }
}
return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

может так надо было ТС

```js
Test = {
    "provide": [],
    "data": [["a","b","c","d"],["e","f"]]
};
var a = Test.data[0];
var b = Test.data[1];
for (var i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
  if (a[i] != undefined) {
    Test.provide.push(a[i]);
  }
  if (b[i] != undefined) {
    Test.provide.push(b[i]);
  }
}
console.log(Test.provide);
```